# Confused - spec_helper.rb:94:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Shoulda (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, shoulda

I am working on a project with Rails 4 & Mongoid 4. I am trying to set up Shoulda-matchers (version 2.8.0), following [thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers), which points to another README called [README for 2.8.0](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/tree/v2.8.0#shoulda-matchers---). And I am hoping to use the [mongoid-rspec](https://github.com/mongoid-rspec/mongoid-rspec) for testing.

**However** I keep getting `spec_helper.rb:94:in '<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Shoulda (NameError)`

I added this in `Gemfile`: following [thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers)

```
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```

I also added in `spec_helper.rb` (Which is where the error comes from) - following [thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#configuration)

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

I have tried googling but there is no direct solution to this (Or there is no direct problem to this). I added `require: false` in the Gemfile, following [README for 2.8.0](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/tree/v2.8.0#shoulda-matchers---)

```
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
end
```

I added `require 'shoulda/matchers'` in the `rails_helper.rb`. My order of 'requires' is this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
```

require 'rspec/rails' is below require 'spec_helper' by default. And by the [README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/tree/v2.8.0#shoulda-matchers---) provided on the github page, I should place `shoulda\matcher` below 'rspec/rails'.  I have also tried to place `require 'shoulda/matchers'` on top of `require 'spec_helper'` but it didn't work.

**My versions:**

```
Rails 4.2.1
Ruby 2.2.1
Mongoid ~ 4.0.0
rspec-rails ~ 3.0
mongoid-rspec ~ 2.1.0
shoulda-matchers 2.8.0
```

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the link you provided:

**NOTE: The new configuration syntax isn't available in a public release just yet -- please refer to the README for 2.8.0 for the current installation instructions.**

That note is from the master branch. The current release (2.8.0) has a different set of documentation. Confusing, I know.

Just remove that configuration section from `spec/spec_helper.rb` and all should be rainbows and unicorns once again.

Comment: Removing what??

Answer (score 0):

Just insert these lines into `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel, type: :model)
config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord, type: :model)
```

Reference:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#availability-of-matchers-in-various-example-groups

Answer (score 0):

add these lines to spec/rails_helper.rb

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).